# Screenshots taken in the work profile are saved in the personal profile

Tags: profiles

When taking a screenshot of any app in my work profile, the picture is saved to my personal profile.

Is this the default/expected behaviour ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it is or it should be the default behavior, but **it is** expected behavior.

Screenshots are taken (through command-line or key combination or tile) and saved by ***System UI*** (`com.android.systemui`) package which is part of stock Android. When deciding where to save the screenshot file, [the path](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r1/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/screenshot/GlobalScreenshot.java#142) is decided (using [`getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) API up to Android 9 or [`MediaStore`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore) on Android 10+) based on the **current `User_ID`** (not `UID`), which is `0` for device owner (personal profile) and `10`, `11`, `12` .... for secondary users/profiles.

Since **profiles** are not completely isolated users but associated to a parent user, separate instances of [only essential apps](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/implement#required_apps) and packages are run under new User_ID. All display related things e.g. notifications, lock screen, status bar etc. in secondary profile are handled by primary user's *System UI* process which is running under User_ID `0` e.g. with UID `10500`. So the screenshot is saved to primary profile's storage i.e. `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/`.

However [**Multiple Users**](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multi-user) are more isolated than profiles and unlike latter, two users cannot share user interface. When you create and switch to a new user (not enabled on all ROMs by OEMs/developers), a separate instance of *System UI* app is run e.g. with UID `1010500`. So the new user has a separate lock screen and doesn't share notifications with primary user. Likewise a screenshot is saved to `/storage/emulated/10/Pictures/Screenshots/`.